# Python files' outputs are ************ regardless of python files that I execute

Tags: python-3.x

Thank you in advance for answering my question.

I tried to execute my python files on Windows command prompt. However, '************' is the only output I can get regardless of the files I execute.

For example, test. py consists of only one-line code which is
'print("Python check")'

troubleshooting_1.py is just the same code as test.py. It consists of
'print("troubleshooting")

I don't know why this problem occurs.

Below is the result of `where python`

```
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\sshackathon_project_2>where python
C:\Users\User\Desktop\sshackathon_project_2\python
C:\Users\User\Desktop\sshackathon_project_2\python.py
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
```

[Windows command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuu4Z.png)

Comment: aha, try `where python` for starters. You could have a `python.bat` shell which echoes **********

Comment: also always post text as text, not images.

Comment: I add a result of `where python`. I tried to post the codes in that image as text, but ' ********** ' turned into a gray line.

Comment: `sshackathon_project_2\python` What's this?  Try renaming everything in this directory that's named `python` to something else.

Comment: or try `python.exe yourscript.py`. Closing as cannot repro

Comment: Oh, that was a cause. I have made a python file named `python` last week. I deleted it and now everything works well :) Thank you! @Jean-FrançoisFabre and @Patrick Haugh I really appreciate it!
Could you explain why making a file named `python` makes problem?

Comment: the PATHEXT must contain ".py" extension so it's running your `python.py` file even without specifying the python extension. You're welcome